# Nested (funcall func) exceeds max-lisp-eval-depth, why?

Tags: elisp, ert

I'm working on two general functions for executing independent unit-tests in elisp. One is about doing something and reset all custom-variables of my package, the other is about doing something in a temp-buffer and reset all custom-variables of my package.

Function (general):

```
(defun package-test-test (func)
    ""
    (unwind-protect
        (funcall func)
      (reset-all-custom-package-variables)))
```

Function (temp-buffer):

```
    (defun package-test-test-in-buffer (func)
        ""
        (package-test-test
            (lambda ()
                (with-temp-buffer (funcall func)))))
```

When i now call: `(package-test-test-in-buffer (lambda () (insert "a")))` it exceeds `max-lisp-eval-depth`, why (there is no recursion)?

Comment: Please enable `debug-on-error` in the options menu and examine the `*Backtrace*` buffer.

Comment: It looks like that it is not allowed two have the same parameter name when calling them later as functions.

Comment: Well you're *allowed* to (hence the symptom of your problem), but what's *happening* is that `package-test-test` binds the variable `func` to a function which itself evals `(funcall func)`, and then it calls that function. Hence the infinite recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the [dynamic binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Scoping.html) which is the default in Emacs Lisp: `func` arguments in your functions are the *same* variable.
You need to rename one of them or use [lexical binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html).

See also [How to live with Emacs Lisp dynamic scoping?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3786033/850781)